# SQL Server 2012: Table data backup in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to take a table's data backup as Excel in SQL Server 2012?

We can get the full database backup by using a maintenance plan automatically in `.bak` format or using import/export wizard to take Excel backup manually.

But I need to take a table's data backup in Excel (`.xlsx/.xls`) after 6 hour time interval automatically. Is it possible in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: You could set up a SSIS package that export that particular table's data into an Excel file, and create a SQL Server agent job to run that package every 6 hours ..

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't be able to do that. The SQL Server backup creates a .BAK file and that is the only option you have. However, what I might suggest you do is to create an SSIS package that takes the data in your database and creates an Excel file, and schedule the SSIS package to fire every 6 hours.

This might be a bit tedious to set up, especially if you have a lot of tables, but it can be done. And, as you probably know, if any of your tables has more than 1M rows, you're going to lose data sending it to Excel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try on your showing path.